# C++ : can't display elements added in a list

Tags: c++

I have a problem when filling in a list in C++. I want to unit two lists factsSource and factsDest (Facts of entity).

The code is as follow :

```
Entity.h :

class Entity
{
public :
    int id;
    string name;
    list <Fact> facts;  
}

Entity.cc

void  Entity::setFactsList2(list <Fact> facts) {

std::list<Fact>::iterator iterator;
for (iterator = facts.begin(); iterator != facts.end(); ++iterator) {
    this->getFactsList().push_back(*iterator);
}
}

//unite two list : factsSource and facts of entity (factsDest)
void Entity::addFacts(list<Fact> factsSource, Entity *entity){

list<Fact> factsDest = entity->getFactsList();
unite(factsSource, &factsDest);
entity->setFactsList2(factsDest);
}

void Entity::unite(list<Fact> factsSource, list<Fact> * factsDest) {

std::list<Fact>::iterator iterator;
for (iterator = factsSource.begin(); iterator != factsSource.end();++iterator) {         
        factsDest->push_back((*iterator).getFactLiteral());        
 }
}

Main class :
std::list<Entity>::iterator iterator3;
for (iterator3 = targetPeers.begin(); iterator3 != targetPeers.end(); ++iterator3) {
    (*iterator3).addFacts(P0.getFactsList(), &(*iterator3));
    //displaying facts
    list<Fact> factsTargetPeer = (*iterator3).getFactsList();
    std::list<Fact>::iterator iter;
    for (iter = factsTargetPeer.begin(); iter != factsTargetPeer.end(); ++iter) {
          ev << (*iter).getFactLiteral().getName() <<endl; // displaying facts
}
}
```

The problem lies when displaying the set of facts. In fact, it only displays factsDest and not the union of the two lists (factsSource and factsDest).

are there errors in codes ?

Thank you for your help in advance,

Comment: What is the signature of `getFactsList` ?

Comment: Please format your code for better readability.

Comment: Lots of list passing-by-value going on there. Don't they teach you about references?

Answer (score 0):

`getFactsList` returns a copy of the list, so `this->getFactsList().push_back(*iterator);` adds to a new list every time.

Use the member directly:

```
void  Entity::setFactsList2(const std::list<Fact>& newFacts) {
    for (std::list<Fact>::const_iterator i = newFacts.begin(); i != newFacts.end(); ++iterator) {
        facts.push_back(*i);
    }
}
```

or

```
void  Entity::setFactsList2(const std::list<Fact>& newFacts) 
{
    std::copy(newFacts.begin(), newFacts.end(), std::back_inserter(facts));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer But when i run it, it's blocked. should i modify the procedure addFacts by changing the type of variable factsDest (list<Fact> => const list<Fact> ?

Comment: when i comment the line of code "this->facts.push_back(*(i));", it works.. Do you have any idea of the problem ??

Comment: When using directly the member "facts" of the class entity, execution is blocked..